# What does $\sum x$ mean when $x$ is a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, operations-research

I am reading a paper. They define the following problem. [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cef29.png)

Notice the equation $\sum p \cdot M = 1$. Now see the definition of $M$ in this snippet from the same paper: [M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQsP5.png)

So, $M$ is some matrix with the same rows as the length of the $p$-vector, which we call $n$.

Then clearly $p\cdot M$ is itself a row vector of length $m$ (the column length of $M$). But then what is $\sum p \cdot M$? What is the sum of a vector? Have the authors made a mistake, or is this some notation I am unfamiliar with?

### EDIT:

The answers say that this is just element-wise addition, but I do not see how this fits.

I will provide context. Consider this tree: [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUOhl.png) Each arc in the tree is associated with a probability. Each node in the tree is the "starting point" of a distribution, corresponding to the arcs that branch off from this node. The first node has a distribution with two outcomes, and the other nodes have a distribution with 3 outcomes each.

$p$ is a vector with $8$ elements. It contains the probabilities on the arcs. $M$ is a matrix of $8$ rows and 3 columns (since we have 3 nodes/3 distributions). The idea is that $p \cdot M$, where $M$ is a matrix of zeros and ones, extracts probabilities for each distribution/for each column/for each node. In this context, how then do we make sense of $\sum pM = 1$?

How would you define $M$ in this case then?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The sum of vectors is usually just the coordinatewise sum, but you haven't included enough context to tell in this case. Please edit the question to give us all the definitions. Use mathjax, not images.

Comment: If $x$ is a vector then vector addition is defined, hence summation. I suppose the limits of summation is implied somewhere.

Comment: Reason would call for it being the sum of the entries.

Comment: It could be shorthand for the sum of the entries of the vector $(pM)$, i.e. assuming the entries are all positive this would otherwise be called the [taxicab norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).  I would have normally seen this as $pM=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k x_i$

Answer (score 1):

Since you write that each column defines a distribution, then this is "somewhat equivalent" that each column is an observation / random variable.

Then, just like the standard axiom for probabilities:

$$\sum_i p_i x_i=1$$

One considers

$$\sum_{i,j} p_i x_{ij}=(1_1,1_2,...,1_{no. \space of \space cols})$$
where $j$ refers to the column and $i$ refers to the row. So for each column one sums over the rows and each such sum must evaluate to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of a vector (at least in this case) is the sum of its entries.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the vector $pM$ contains probabilities. The condition then says that the sum of the probabilities of all possible options should equal 1.

Comment: Yes, but $pM$ does not contain the probabilities of one particular distribution. It contains the probabilities of *each* distribution. Therefore, $\sum pM = 1$ makes no sense. If we have $p_1 + p_2 = 1$ and $q_1 + q_2 = 1$ for two distributions, then $\sum pM = 1$ corresponds to saying $p_1 + p_2 + q_1 + q_2 = 1$... Which is of course wrong.

Comment: You've not given me enough context to help you out any further. The only reasonable interpretation of $\sum pM = 1$ is that it means that the sum of the entries of $pM$ equals 1. My best guess is that either there is a mistake in the paper, or that you've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

From the little context given, one can imagine that in $\sum p\cdot M=1$, the $1$ in the RHS denotes a vector of ones.

---

**Update:**

The explanation is given just above: "constraints defining the probabilities to be nonnegative
and to sum up to one". The sum of the components of the vector $pM$ equals $1$.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: @Oeao: do you disagree with my answer ?

Comment: If $pM$ is itself a vector, and $1$ is also a vector of ones, then what are we taking the sum over? Then we ought to just have $pM = 1$, no? Basically my problem is the $\sum$-notation. If we just had $pM = 1$, where $1$ is a vector of ones, I have no problem. It all makes sense. But the $\sum$ has me confused.

Comment: @Oeao: indeed, a summation makes sense if you have a set of pairs $p,M$, and there should be indices. It could also be that $\sum$ denotes a scalar constant ! Again the context you provide is insufficient.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/77f9/cd4988536db46bc16110c4a0b58cbd2d513e.pdf Here's the paper, the relevant parts are from page 297-298. Start from where it says "2. Model description", and then read 1 page onwards from that. It's an easy read, no prerequisites required, should take you a 1 minute.

Comment: @Oeao: please avoid comments like "should take you a 1 minute". This is untrue and disparaging.